# C# WPF DataGrid uniform columns size reduction

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, size

It is necessary to evenly reduce the size of the columns by dragging the right edge as it is implemented in the Visual Studio.

How to uniformly resize a table by dragging the right border?

Below is an example of how you can resize in Visual Studio.
Before change:
[image: Before change]
After change:
[image: After change]

Tried adjusting the DataGrid settings, but that didn't help

```
<DataGrid 
      x:Name="MainDataGridDop"  
      IsEnabled="{Binding AppUnlocked}"
      SelectionMode="Single"
      GridLinesVisibility="All"
      HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
      VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
      AlternationCount="2"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      FrozenColumnCount ="2" 
      CanUserAddRows="False" 
      CanUserSortColumns="False"
      ItemsSource="{Binding AddVolumesServiceList}"
      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedAddVolumesRow, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
      MouseRightButtonDown="MainDataGridDop_MouseRightButtonDown"
      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"                                         
      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
      UseLayoutRounding="False"
      BorderBrush="#FFDDDDDD" 
      Background="#FFF9F9F9"
      CanUserResizeColumns="True"
      MinWidth="150" Width="Auto" MinHeight="15" ColumnWidth="*" Margin="0,0,0,1"
>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to uniformly resize a table by dragging the right border?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add this property to your datagrid.

```
CanUserResizeColumns="true"
```

Or if you want to make a specific width to every column just remove the wildcard character and type specific width for every column if you want.

Forexample:

```
ColumnWidth="120,120,50,50,*"
```

Comment: This does not work

Comment: Can you send here a proper illustration about what you want exactly?